# Mixing abstract classes and templates, a recipe for disaster?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm having problems with the following situation.  I have three classes that are involved in this mixup.  `List`, `ListNode`, `City`.  I have a `List<City *>`, where the list will be made up of a set of `ListNode<City *>` (standard wrapper around the list nodes).

City is an abstract class, so there are several classes that inherit from it that could be placed in this list and accessed polymorphically.  The List class has a `getHead()` method which returns a pointer to a `ListNode` that is the head.

Any city has a population, so to access the populations, I'd expect the following to work.  It's not, thus my question.  I broke it down into pieces to make it simpler along the way:

```
    ListNode<City *> *head= country->city_list->getHead();
    City *headnode = *head->getNode();

    cout << "Test: " << headnode->getPopulation() << endl;
```

`getPopulation()` returns an integer.  `country` is defined as `List<City*> *city;`  Any help on how I could figure out my problem would be greatly appreciated.

**edit** adding more code for better idea of what I'm working with.  First, ListNode:

```
template <class T>
class ListNode
{
public:
    ListNode() {next = 0;node = 0;};

    ListNode(T *t) {node = t; next = 0;};

    ListNode(const ListNode &l)
    {
        //long copy constructor. snip.
    };

    T *getNode() const { return node; }
    ListNode *getNext() const { return next; };

private:
    T *node;
    ListNode *next;
};
```

Now, here is what might relevant in the List class..

```
template <class T>
class List
{
public:
    List()
    {
        head = 0;
        size = 0;
    };

    List(ListNode<T> *t)
    {
        head = t;
        size = 1;
    };

    List(T *t)
    {
        head = new ListNode<T>(t);
        size = 1;
    };

    List(const List<T> &t)
    {
        // long copy constructor. snip.
    };
    //bunch of irrelevent methods.


    ListNode<T> *getHead() const {return head;};

    List &operator+=(T &t)
    {
        this->insert(&t);
        size++;
        return (*this);
    };


private:
    List &insert(T *t)
    {
        ListNode<T> *current = head;
        if (current == 0)
        {
            head = new ListNode<T>(t);
        }
        else
        {
            while (current->getNext() != 0)
            {
                current = current->getNext();
            }
            current->setNext(new ListNode<T>(t));
        }
        return (*this);
    };

    ListNode<T> *head;
    int size;
};
```

I have a hunch that the process of inserting might be the problem.  I insert with the List class's += operator, shown in the List implementation above.  It calls the private insert method shown above, as well.  It looks like this:
City *somecity = new City(x,y,z); //some parameters. integers.
*city_list += somecity; // where city_list is a List.

Comment: The only reason I can think of for implementing your own `List` instead of using `std::list` is homework. If that is the case, please add the homework tag. If not, think really hard if you could not simply use `std::list` or `std::vector`.

Comment: But...what actually is not working? What errors do you get? What is `blah`?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - Not legitimately homework.  At least not school homework.  I've been spending the past 2 days or so trying to refresh on my C++, and I'm using these examples as learning tools.  With that said, feel free to treat it as you would treat any other homework, since that is the best way for me to learn

Comment: The errors I get are at runtime.  "Unhandled exception at 0x01087a30 in refresher.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4589009b."

Comment: Ok. So you need to post more code:-). It looks like there's something wrong with pointers.

Comment: @vapo that usually means you have a pointer accessing an invalid memory location. Is the correct amount of space allocated and the pointer isn't referring to something it isn't suppose to?

Comment: That is the sort of error that's best examined with a debugger.

Comment: @vapo: There's no way we can see what's going wrong here without more code

Comment: Is everything initialized that needs to be?

Comment: You need to post more code to figure out what the actual problem is. However in general I think your design is a little broken. There is nothing wrong with using templates and base classes but your list implementation seems to violate at least one OO principle: encapsulation. You should not need to access internals of a list to get to an element. Having to use `list->get_list()->get_head()->get_node()` sounds wrong.

Comment: The debugger doesn't seem to be able to show me specific templated contents.  I'm using VS2010.  Been trying to run through it with the debugger.  I guess the provided code has no issues then?  Hmm

Comment: This code is semantically correct. Which line is exactly crashing your app? Can you post the code for `List`?

Comment: Accessing headnode()->getPopulation() is crashing.  It doesn't seem to be able to qualify headnode() to its specific type or instance.  I'll post more code for List, although it's huge.  I'll try to cut it down

Comment: Ok, I think I spotted a typo. Please see me answer.

Comment: Right, it wouldn't compile this was a problem.

Comment: I'm having a hunch that the insertion might be the problem.  I've updated my question a bit.  Does this look right?

Comment: Hey, you should be instantiating your classes with `City` as a template argument. Since you're using `City*` your are effectively storing `City**` in `ListNode` (and others). This is why you're pointers get messed up latter.

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming that it would need to be a City* to be accessed polymorphically then?  City is a base abstract class, in which this list will be full of classes that inherit from city.

Comment: It will work just fine. `City` is just a template arg. You use `T*` everywhere in your code, so you'll end up with `City*` when accessing anyway. Which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a variable scoping problem.

Your `ListNode` class contains a pointer to the node value.  Your `ListNode` constructor takes in a pointer to the node value and saves it.

The problem is if that pointer is to a local variable that then goes out of scope.  Your `ListNode`'s node pointer is now pointing to an object that doesn't exist. e.g. in this example

```
addToList(List<int>& myList)
{
    int x = 3;
    myList += x;  // pointer to x is in the list
}
// Out of scope; x no longer exists, but myList has a pointer to it.
// Accessing this node will result in an error.
```

There are a couple possible remedies:

1. Have your `ListNode` contain values rather than pointers.  The drawback here is that you will be making copies of the values
2. Implement  `ListNode` using a reference counted smart pointer which will manager the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Is this an issue if I'm always allocating on the heap though?  I figure if you never add a local variable to the list, it should be fine?  Or is there a deeper issue?

Comment: If you're always using the heap, you would only get in trouble if the pointer gets deleted.

So this may not be *the* problem, but it would still be a problem with the class design because it is very easy to use incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you could do is:

```
ListNode<City *>* head = new ListNode<City*>(country->city_list->getHead());
City* headnode = head->getNode();

cout << "Test: " << headnode->getPopulation() << endl;
```

It will take the existing `City` (on the memory) and put it at the head of the List node, and so on.

and if you want to copy them, maybe you could just make this:

```
ListNode<City *>* head = new ListNode<City*>*(new City(country->city_list->getHead()));
City* headnode = new City(head->getNode());

cout << "Test: " << headnode->getPopulation() << endl;
```

Hope it will help you.